# bash file is not working for executing python file on fedora

Tags: python, cron

I had created a python script for example `test.py` and path of the file is `/Desktop/test.py`

i want to run the file using cron jobs, so decided to create a bash script with name `test.sh` with the code below

**test.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd /Desktop/test.py
python test.py 2>log.txt
```

but this not working, when i tried to test it like below i am getting error as given below

```
sh-4.2$ python test.sh
  File "test.sh", line 4
    python test.py 2>log.txt 
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If this works fine then i can open cron tab with `crontab -e` and can execute with the following command

```
/2 * * * * /path/to/bashscript/test.sh
```

Can anyone make this work will appreciated.........

Answer (score 2):

because you are trying to run a `bash` file through python!

error:  `python test.sh`

you should instead `bash test.sh`

Comment: when i run bash test.sh the following is displayed sh-4.2$ bash test.sh 
test.sh: line 3: cd: /Desktoptest.py: No such file or directory
sucess (I am not running this file from here /Desktop/ , i am in another folder, bu t when i run the command bash test.sh from Desktop its executing and showiing below)

Comment: test.sh: line 3: cd: /Desktop/test.py: No such file or directory
sucess

Comment: because /Desktop doesn't exist. it should be `cd ~/Desktop/test.py`

Comment: k i had used cd ~/Desktop/test.py and its working fine when i ran separately with bash test.sh and now i tried to run this bash file test.sh in cron tabs so i had opened crontab -e and then the following command */2 * * * * /Desktop/test.sh,then the error is as below

Comment: crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.BT50GL":1: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?

Answer (score 2):

You need no bash-script for that.

You can do all things you do in the script in crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * cd ${HOME}/Desktop/; python test.py 2> log.txt
```

Comment: k first i opened crontab -e then typed the command as above given, then it is displaying the below error crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.M0WAYC":1: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.M0WAYC

Comment: What have you entered? `*/2 * * * *` or `/2 * * * *`?

Comment: i have entered this */2 * * * *

Comment: @Igor Chubin : can i know whats happening here

Comment: `*/2 * * * *` is correct. That means: run this every two minutes. Can you try `* * * * *`?

Comment: yes i tried that worked actually and got this crontab: installing new crontab

Comment: but need to run after every 2 min or 5 min

Comment: then you must use `*/2`. Or, if it is not supported by your cron (it is really stragne; which version of linux you have?), you must write: `1,3,5,7,9,...`

Comment: actually i am using fedora 15

Comment: I tried again its not working with */2 and working with * * * * *

Comment: fedora 15 supports */2 of course. May be your editor wrap the line? Can you please check that this line is not splitted?

Comment: actually i just copying and pasting the above command and saving it with :wq thats all

Comment: can you please make `crontab -l > file` then edit the file, save it, and then show the result on pastebin.com?